# Integration with respect to a signed measure on $[0,1]$

Tags: measure-theory, signed-measures

Let $x^*$ be a signed measure on $[0,1]$. I just want to make sense of the following steps.

$$\int_{[0,1]}(s\wedge t)x^* (ds)=\int_0^t s x^*(ds)+t\int_t^1 x^*(ds)= \int_0^tx^* ([s,1])ds$$

I just don't understand the last equality. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the last equality true for a positive measure?  For a difference of two positive measures?

Comment: @GEdgar I don't know how to work this out for a positive measure as well. Sorry

Comment: Fubini.  Fix $t$, $0 < t < 1$.  Use the set $A_t := \{(s,x) : 0 \le x \le t, x \le s \le 1\}$